# Convert string to timestamp in Impala

Tags: string, casting, timestamp, impala

How can I convert a `string` representing a datetime in the format `"YYYY-MM-DD;HH:MM:SS"` (i.e. `2016-04-11;19:38:01`) to a proper `timestamp`?

I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

```
select 
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date`, "YYYY-MM-DD;HH:MM:SS"))
from t1
limit 100;
```

Comment: This returns "WARNINGS: Bad date/time conversion format: YYYY-MM-DD;HH:MM:SS". If you read the manual, it says that capitalization matters. Here it is: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html. You're looking for the section on from_unixtime to explain how to use the format in unix_timestamp.

Answer (score 8):

The return type of `from_unixtime()` isn't a "proper `timestamp`" but a string. (And the return type of `unix_timestamp()` isn't... a `timestamp`, but a `bigint`).

Here is what I do to get a `timestamp` return type:

```
select
  cast(unix_timestamp(`date`, "yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss") as timestamp)
from t1
limit 100;
```

For the sake of completeness, here is how I deal with timezones, locally formatted dates, and storing them as UTC timestamps:

```
select
  to_utc_timestamp(cast(unix_timestamp(`date`, "yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss") as timestamp), "Europe/Paris")
from t1
limit 100;
```

This assumes the `-use_local_tz_for_unix_timestamp_conversions` startup flag is off (this is the default).

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @jbapple in a comment to my question, the issue is with the capitalization. As stated in the Impala documentation

> Currently, the format string is case-sensitive, especially to
>   distinguish m for minutes and M for months. In Impala 1.3 and later,
>   you can switch the order of elements, use alternative separator
>   characters, and use a different number of placeholders for each unit.
>   Adding more instances of y, d, H, and so on produces output strings
>   zero-padded to the requested number of characters. The exception is M
>   for months, where M produces a non-padded value such as 3, MM produces
>   a zero-padded value such as 03, MMM produces an abbreviated month name
>   such as Mar, and sequences of 4 or more M are not allowed. A date
>   string including all fields could be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
>   "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", "MMM dd, yyyy HH.mm.ss (SSSSSS)" or
>   other combinations of placeholders and separator characters.

The right way of writing it is:

```
select 
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date`, "yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss")) 
from t1 
limit 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers involving `unix_timestamp` worked for me running Impala on Cloudera v5. 
But a simple `select cast('1985-09-25 17:45:30.005' as timestamp);` works.

See this [doc](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_timestamp.html#timestamp)